# Eclipse link web projects java build path

Tags: eclipse, debugging, build, path, project

In Eclipse have a java web project and I want to link it to another java project. Saying that:

Project A: Web project

Project B: Another java project

Normally can you achieve it by going  to the properties of project A -> Java build path -> Projects and add the project B.

However if project A is a web project running inside tomcat then at runtime I receive a ClassNotFoundException for the classes of project B.

One solution to to problem is to export project B as a jar file and use it inside project A (put it in the WEB-INF/lib directory).

However this is not the case because I want also to debug at the same time project A AND project B

Comment: Why not make it a single project to be able to debug them?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project A's Deployment Assembly property page and add Project B as a project Directive Type.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I found one good solution.

In eclipse from the properties of project A go: Java Build Path -> Source -> Link Source

in the "linked folder location" give the src folder of project B and in "Folder name" just put "src2" (just something different from "src").

This way eclipse creates a symbolic folder src2 which links classes of project B to the space of project A.

After that everything works fine:

1. You can compile and run project A without any ClassNotFound Exception.
2. You can debug classes from both Project A and project B at runtime.
3. Classes from project B are kept in a separate folder in the filesystem totally independent (this is also useful when you use a source control system like SVN, because two projects continue to be independent). Notice that even folder "src2" is not a real one, so no change in project A.